# Make Ajax call inside WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I am developing a Swift 2 based iOS application. I have an embedded WKWebView which essentially shows me a webpage from a pre-configured URL. What I am actually looking for is to make an Ajax call through an embedded JavaScript on that webpage. I put in the code for the Ajax call, but it goes into the error part, giving me a **Content Security Policy Exception**.

I am looking for a way to make the call such that I do not get those sort of errors.

Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Do you have the code you used?